# Why is `kivy` seen as a variable rather than a module?

Tags: python, import, scope, kivy

The following code runs without errors.

```
import kivy
def main():
    try:
        kivy.require('1.9.2')
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        #import kivy.base
if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    main()
```

However, if I un-comment line 8, it prints:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 4, in main
     kivy.require('1.9.2')
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kivy' referenced before assignment
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is `kivy` on line 4 recognized as a variable instead of a module?
2. How does line 8 affect whether line 4 raises an exception?

Comment: This is answered by a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use and https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've hit the standard global/local behaviour described e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370357/2469283), but obfuscated slightly by the fact that you're assigning to the variable via importing.

Note that the `kivy` variable isn't special just because you assigned to it via an import, it's still a variable name that follows normal reassignment and referencing rules.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer with more detail, but I'll accept this. You're right - it's the global/local issue. To make it do what I intended, I needed to add `global kivy` just before the `kivy.require()` line.